# Receiving [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException] email using Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.5, laravel-migrations

Am following a tutorial attempting to learn how to use Laravel5.5. After following a step which said to add `protected $fillable = array('email', 'password', 'name');` to the User model.

Which I'm assuming is setting which fields are mass assignable fields? The next step was to add:

```
User::create(array(
    'email' => 'your@email.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
    'name' => 'John Doe'
));
```

Which I'm to understand is to add said user to the db.

When I run `php artisan migrate` I receive `[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException] email` and I have no idea why. I have tried adding `Eloquent::unguard()`, have tried to make it all guardable.

Have removed email from the fillable array. Have got rid of email altogther.

Each time I run `php artisan migrate` the error is this same.

Comment: Where are you using the code for User::create? Are you using model factory for seeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work without any problems based on your description.

So make sure:

- you are using valid User model (maybe you have 2 and you set fillable only in one of them)?
- you are not inserting other data in migrations. It's quite possible the problem is for other model and not for User model.

Comment: I've checked User models and there seems to be one which is empty and one which I created. 

The other migrations are inserting data but not for an `email` field. It seems as though the tutorial I'm following might be based on Laravel 4 so I may need to stop and find one based on 5.5.

Comment: Idea about fillable and MassAssignment wasn't change so for sure there is wrong something else

Comment: It was issues with trying to add fake users via the migration.